# How do I apply pagination.js to handle Google Sheets json

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use pagination.js to call a json from Google Sheets and present the data. However, I can't seem to pass the data from the jquery call into the data display. I've logged the data into the console, but I can't seem to pass it into the templating function. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in passing the data in this codepen: https://codepen.io/stewartjohn/pen/VBzNdq.

```
function simpleTemplating(data) {
  var html = '<ul>';
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    html += '<li>' + value.gsx$title.$t + '</li>';
  });
  html += '</ul>';
  return html;
};

var sheetUrl = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1cOLwDw0BzgTLHf_1VHszFlB4jACFkH3Iva21aIA4Zb8/1/public/values?alt=json'

$('#pagination-container').pagination({
  dataSource: function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    var self = this
    xhr.open('GET', sheetUrl)
    xhr.onload = function() {
      self.entries = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
      self.entries = self.entries.feed.entry
      console.log(self.entries)
    }
    xhr.send()
  },
  pageSize: 6,
  totalNumber: 34,
  callback: function(data, pagination) {
    var html = simpleTemplating(data);
    $('#data-container').html(html);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undestand your requirements correctly, then this can be achieved by reogranizing your code ([here's my codepen showing the full solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EpwZZa)).

By shifting the code that calls the `paginagation()` plugin, into your  xhr's `onload` handler, the entries returned from the server can be paginated as follows:

```
// Invoke the ajax request first
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', sheetUrl)
xhr.onload = function () {       

  var entries = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
  entries = entries.feed.entry
  console.log(entries)

  // Once data has been loaded, then setup your paginataion instance and load 
  // the entries into the paginataion plugin
  $('#pagination-container').pagination({
      dataSource: entries,
      pageSize: 6,
      totalNumber: 34,
      callback: function(data, pagination) {
          var html = simpleTemplating(data);
          $('#data-container').html(html);
      }
  })
}

xhr.send()
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it has resolved your initial question